# Javafx maven project deployment with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I Started a JavaFX maven project in Intellij IDEA. 
The programme run perfectly inside Intellij IDEA.
I have Included javafx-maven-plugin in order to deploy the my project.
After executing the javafx-maven-plugin:jfx:build-jar. i got this error log :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=15.0.1 --debug -T X org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\computerPCNRU\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\computerPCNRU\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for C:\Users\computerPCNRU\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted:EntrepriseLimited:jar:1.0: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted:EntrepriseLimited:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 11, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted:EntrepriseLimited:jar:1.0
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[WARNING] Couldn't parse thread count, will default to 1.0: X
[DEBUG] Thread pool size: 1
[INFO] Building with 1 threads
[DEBUG] Scheduling: MavenProject: com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted:EntrepriseLimited:1.0 @ D:\Projects\6.Project SI limted\2 nd iteration\2. Object Oriented design\pom.xml
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building EntrepriseLimited 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted:EntrepriseLimited:1.0
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <altDeploymentRepository>${altDeploymentRepository}</altDeploymentRepository>
  <artifact default-value="${project.artifact}"/>
  <attachedArtifacts default-value="${project.attachedArtifacts}"/>
  <localRepository default-value="${localRepository}"/>
  <offline default-value="${settings.offline}"/>
  <packaging default-value="${project.packaging}"/>
  <pomFile default-value="${project.file}"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <retryFailedDeploymentCount default-value="1">${retryFailedDeploymentCount}</retryFailedDeploymentCount>
  <skip default-value="false">${maven.deploy.skip}</skip>
  <updateReleaseInfo default-value="false">${updateReleaseInfo}</updateReleaseInfo>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-cli) @ EntrepriseLimited ---
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.sonatype.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6d06d69c]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted:EntrepriseLimited:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = []
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =        id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/computerPCNRU/.m2/repository/
   layout: none

[DEBUG]   (f) offline = false
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = D:\Projects\6.Project SI limted\2 nd iteration\2. Object Oriented design\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted:EntrepriseLimited:1.0 @ D:\Projects\6.Project SI limted\2 nd iteration\2. Object Oriented design\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) retryFailedDeploymentCount = 1
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.095s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Feb 28 23:48:32 WAT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/61M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-cli) on project EntrepriseLimited: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-cli) on project EntrepriseLimited: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleThreadedBuilder$1.call(LifecycleThreadedBuilder.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleThreadedBuilder$1.call(LifecycleThreadedBuilder.java:163)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.getDeploymentRepository(DeployMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 11 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Her is the pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted</groupId>
    <artifactId>EntrepriseLimited</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>main</mainClass>
                    <bundler>EXE</bundler>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.abdo.EntrepriseLimted</groupId>
            <artifactId>EntrepriseLimited</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You'd better re-invoke maven with the "debug output" option (`mvn -X <goals...>`) and post the complete log.

Comment: You must declare the dependencies as part of your pom.xml.

Comment: I'm not using command line, i'm using maven plugin

Comment: how i can add dependencies as part of pom.xml

Comment: The relevant log output is: `Input folder does not exist [D:\Projects\6.Project SI limted\2. Object Oriented design\target\classes]`, can you verify that?

Comment: Yes, the target\classes exists in my project

Comment: I have updated the post after using debug out

Comment: Why you add same artifact as dependencies to the pom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check to your settings.xml in .m2 repository location. If distribution management is configured, then you need to specify the same in your pom.